# VBScript - Retrieving a Scalar Value From a Stored Procedure on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, ado

My stored procedure is very simple. It inserts a new record. At the end of it I have the following line:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

1) Am I using the right code to return the Primary Key value for the newly inserted record?
2) How do I retrieve this value using ASP Classic/VBScript with ADO Classic?

```
Dim cmdUA
Set cmdUA = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmdUA.ActiveConnection = tcon
cmdUA.CommandText = "InsertUserAgent"
cmdUA.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
cmdUA.Parameters.Append cmdUA.CreateParameter("useragent", adVarWChar, _
adParamInput, 1000)
cmdUA("useragent") = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
cmdUA.Exec
'Here I need to get the value returned from the stored procedure
Set cmdUA.ActiveConnection = Nothing
Set cmdUA = Nothing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Execute method (NOT Exec) returns a record set which contains the result from the stored procedure.

```
 Set rs = cmdUA.Execute
 result = rs.Fields(0).Value
```

Comment: I had to use rs(0) instead of rs.Fields(0).Value but I'm not sure why. Also, to any newbie who might later view this answer, 'rs' is a recordset variable and 'result' is also a variable, both of them undeclared here.