# How to return COUNT(*) and store it in a Variable for further usage in VBscript

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript

I am new to Vbscript (3 days to be precise),

I am connecting my script to SQL Server and playing around with databases. I have connected successfully

Now here's what I want to do:

I want to store the value of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A` in a variable to be used in VBscript.

This SQL query returns the number of rows in table and it is an integer, but how do I return it and save in a variable?

I tried this:

```
Dim VARX
SET VARX = connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A")
```

So now `VARX` should contain the number of rows of `TABLE_A`.

But this is a wrong way I know. And of course It posts an error "TYPE Mismatch:". Please guide me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
Dim rs, varx
SET rs = connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A")
varx = rs(0).value
```

Not my field of expertise actually, here are some references :

- http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1632757
- [VBScript - Retrieving a Scalar Value From a Stored Procedure on SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768004/vbscript-retrieving-a-scalar-value-from-a-stored-procedure-on-sql-server-2008)

Comment: The second Set is wrong. The value returned is a simple number, not an object.

Comment: @Anantvaibhav you're welcome. BTW, why unmarked this answer? (is it the updated code didn't work for you?)

Comment: @har07, As I said, It worked with some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code which worked:

```
...
Set Recordset=CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
ConnString="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=PCX\SQLEXPRESS;UID=sa;PWD=password;DATABASE=testdb"

Dim SQL_Rows, NoOfRows

SQL_Rows = "SELECT Count (*) from Table_A"
Recordset.open SQL_Rows,ConnString
NoOfRows = Recordset(0).value
Recordset.close

MsgBox NoOfRows
```

Now Message Box shows the number of rows in table_A